# Wordpress Form POST Request In Current Page Got Twice

Tags: php, wordpress, email, post, request

I use wordpress shortcode to create a form and send post request in current page.
But I will get twice post request so my mail will send twice.
Hope someone can help me to fix this problem.
Here is my code :

```
<?php 
   if(isset($_POST['flag']) && $_POST['flag'] == 'true') {            
      $message = 'MAIL CONTENT';
      $headers = array('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
      wp_mail(["sender1@xxx.com", "sender2@xxx.com"], 'subject', $message, $headers);
?>
      <script>
           window.setTimeout(function() {
               window.location.href = '<?=home_url()?>'+'/my-account/bookings/';
           }, 3000);
      </script>
<?php
   }else{
?>
      <div class="reupload-wrapper">
          <form action="" method="post" name="reupload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <input type="hidden" name="flag" value="true">
                <label for="files">File</label>
                <input type="file" class="files" name="files" id="file1" accept=".jpg, .jpeg">
                <button id="submit" type="submit" class="button">Submit</button>
          </form>
      </div>
<?php
   }
?>
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with "getting post request twice" ... `wp_mail(["sender2@xxx.com", "sender2@xxx.com"]` - you passed an array for the `$to` parameter that contains the recipient address twice, so you get the mail twice ...

Comment: Sorry. I accidentally made a typo.
That's two different recipients

Comment: Okay, so the form you have shown above, is that the one we are talking about? Because I can't see any field named `flag` in there. And the whole code is supposed to be part of a shortcode?

Comment: Yes it's part of a shortcode.

flag is a hidden input.

Comment: Can you check in your browser dev tools, network panel, what requests are actually happening? Do you really see two POST requests in there?

Comment: I only get one POST request. But I really got two emails, And I got the data twice using error_log to print $_POST.

Comment: So it looks like the code gets executed twice then, within the same request/response cycle. Can you give more details on how/where exactly this gets embedded?

Comment: OK, email is when a user uploads a picture and sends it
Notifications will be sent to sender1@xxx.com and sender2@xxx.com
The user will then be redirected to myaccount

The page embedded in this shortcode is the page the user enters through the link in the notification email.
I use elementor's sortcode element
This page has only one shortcode element

Comment: Can't tell what would make it execute twice in that setting. But perhaps you can work around the problem by setting a global flag. `global $alreadySent; if(!$alreadySent) { /*send mail*/ $alreadySent = true; }` or something like that ...